# Onclick rerouting to url although button is disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to only redirect to the link when the button `disabled="false"`, or when the button is NOT disabled.

When button `disabled="true"`, I **don't** want the button onclick event to redirect the provided URL

Here is my code:

```js
<button
      className="link__infoContainer"
      onClick={(e) => (window.location = `http://${linkUrl}`)}
      disabled="true"
    >
      <p>{linkTitle}</p>
    </button>
```

Comment: I believe you want `disabled={true}`

Comment: hahah that worked! Why does it have to be in brackets???

Comment: Well you want to use the boolean `true`, not the string `"true"`

Comment: Right! I keep forgetting about the types. New to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Roger, you are missing something here I guess, if you set disabled={true} then it wan't trigger onClick event at all on click of button.  let me know in more detail if my answer is not sufficient.

and the code should be

```
<button
  className="link__infoContainer"
  onClick={(e) => (window.location = `http://${linkUrl}`)}
  disabled={true}
>
  <p>{linkTitle}</p>
</button>
```

value for disabled prop must be boolean value not string